# Как заменить тип переменной при помощи #define?

Tags: c++, define

На протяжении всей программы необходимо работать с большими данными, но писать вместо int везде long long int крайне неудобно. Слышал про способ с использованием #define.
Написал:

```
#define int long long int
```

Но выдает ошибку, мол, функция main должна возвращать тип int.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо написать

```
#define int long long
```

Но чтобы компилятор не ругался исправить функцию main:

```
signed main()
{
...
}
```

Теперь код будет компилироваться, и отныне все int станут long long.
Данный метод полезен и оправдан только в олимпиадном (спортивном) программировании для удобства и ускорения написания кода.
В промышленном его же использовать нельзя (если работу потерять не хотите), т.к. код неоправданно дольше работает

Answer (score 9):

Создайте **новый** тип, вернее, синоним типа. Что-то вроде

```
typedef long long int large;
```

или

```
using large = long long int;
```

Ну, или используйте вместо `large` какое-то иное имя. И используйте его везде, где нужно. Если потом нужно будет его заменить - это можно будет сделать в месте определения и все.

Заменять глобально все `int` на `long long int` - как и вообще любое ключевое слово на что-то иное - решение, чреватое большими неприятностями...

Comment: Долго думал, принимать ли правку, в итоге решил отклонить (не соответствует намерениям автора) и поправить опечатку. Перепроверьте пожалуйста, у вас int -> long long int правильно или всё же вам правильно указали что нужно long long int -> int

Answer (score 2):

`#define` крайне не практично, для этого есть `typedef`

```
#include <iostream>

typedef long long int64;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

int main()
{
    int64 a = 9223372036854775807;
    uint64 b = 18446744073709551615;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Но можно воспользоваться ванильными `int64_t` или `uint64_t`

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int64_t a = 9223372036854775807;
    uint64_t b = 18446744073709551615;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы пользоваться `::int64_t` надо подключать `stdint.h`, а чтобы пользоваться `::std::int64_t` надо подключать `cstdint`. Но главное, что их использование вовсе не отменяет необходимости в надлежащих пользовательских алиасах.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Никаких осмысленных способов "подменить" ключевое слово языка не существует. И препроцессор вам в этом не поможет. Если код напрямую ссылается на фундаментальные типы, то "подменить" эти типы не получится.

Переписывайте код так, чтобы вместо прямого использования фундаментальных типов он использовал имена-псевдонимы, определенные вами через `typedef` (или `using`). В таком варианте вы сможете легко подменять типы так, как вам заблагорассудится.

Правильное использование таких имена-псевдонимов потребует бОльших усилий, чем просто определения `typedef`, но ничего из ряда вон выходящего там нет.